# Firebase onCall functions resulting "Unhandled Internal error"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Simply, when a button is clicked, I want to fire a "getUerData" cloud function where it should update target document in firestore. However, it just keeps giving me `unhandled internal error` and I can't narrow down what is causing the problem. I tried just returning `user` data it works fine.

```js
exports.getUserData = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const user = await admin.auth().getUser(data.userId);

  return user       -> no error
});
```

But when I try to modify `doc` it throws me an error

```
Unhandled error /srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/collection-group.js:54
    async *getPartitions(desiredPartitionCount) {
          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js:39:28)
```

Does it have to do with `admin.firestore()`?? or is it the function itself

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.getUserData = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const user = await admin.auth().getUser(data.userId);

  return admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('tweets')
    .doc(data.docId)
    .update({ user: { avatar: user.photoURL, fullName: user.displayName } });
});
```

This function above gets called on onClick event on a button

```js
 const getUserInfo = async () => {
    const getUserData = fbFunctions.httpsCallable('getUserData');

    try {
      const user = await getUserData({ userId: 'userId', docId: 'docId'});
      console.log(user);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error has occured:', err.message);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show any logs you see in the Firebase console for your function.  Or any other debugging information you have.  Just saying "it just wouldn't work" isn't very helpful.

Comment: Please find a full error message I just updated!

Comment: You will either need to upgrade to node 10, or downgrade your firebase-admin SDK.  node 8 is nearly fully deprecated and no longer supported.

Comment: @DougStevenson downgraded admin SDK to "^8.10.0" and it works now. Thanks